# Can I change icon of office addin command button on completion of any event

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins

Here I am trying implement an email tracking system through office addin command button and I want to change the button-icon immediately when track event is completed.Please give your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

We don't support runtime changes of the button icon. But it's a good idea. Please suggest this at [Office Developer User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).